# CakePHP / PHP If Statement User Login Error / Issue - Both conditions are set true?

Tags: php, cakephp, if-statement, authentication

I am using CakePHP 2.2.2 and building session information with it, to store all the users login details, so that I can access them though out my whole site. The code I have written is below:

```
    if (($GetPass == $this->data['Menu']['password'] && $GetUsers == $this->data['Menu']['username'])) {
        $this->Session->write('LoginData', array(
                    'FristName' => $SQL[$key]['User']['fristname'],
                    'SurName' => $SQL[$key]['User']['surname'],
                    'UserName' => $SQL[$key]['User']['username'],
                    'AccessLevel' => $SQL[$key]['Role']['title'],
                    'Email' => $SQL[$key]['User']['email']
                    ));
    } else {
       $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry Login Details Do Not Match Our Records', array('element' => 'failure'));

    }
```

The issue I have with this is driving me up the wall, both conditions are always true. So even if the username & password are within the database, it is still setting the flash message? I just can not see why? The 'else' part of a if statement should only run if the conditions set within the if statement are false, right? So why is my flash message always being set?

Comment: why not using the standard Auth component stuff? as everyone else? cleaner, more secure and working out of the box.

Comment: Well I might now have a look at doing that. The 1st time I did that I could not get it to work. But the problem is still there, as far as I can see my if statement is fine, so why does it set the flash message even if my statement is true. If statements should not do that, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two reasons, first the password field you get from CakePHP Model might be encrypted. Use `debug($GetPass);` and check if it is encrypted or not. Second you are trying to use $this->data in controller which should be `$this->request->data`. Standard way to do what you are trying to do is given here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html